# installing perf on RedHat

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, perf

I read about `perf` tool and I was interested in using in my RedHat.
On Ubuntu it is enough to call `sudo apt-get install linux-tools-2.6.38-11`.

What about RED HAT? I tried both:

```
yum install linux-tools
yum install perf
```

...but it doesn't work.

Do you know where I can get the source code so that I can compile it on my own?
Currently the YUM repository is pointing to a server having most packages we usually install, but maybe it is missing this package.

What repository can I add to download it?

Are my call to yum correct? I read that call from http://joysofprogramming.com/install-perf-fedora-rhel/

Thanks a lot

p.s. below details about my machine

```
uname -a
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)

cat /etc/redhat-release
Linux lndbxdev01 2.6.24.7-108.el5rt #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Mon Mar 23 10:58:10 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the error message

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
myrepository                                           |  951 B     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package perf available.
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Re: "doesn't work" -- what was the actual error message?

Answer (score 5):

perf is new enough that it's not available in RHEL 5.x, IIRC it was added only in kernel 2.6.31. It's there in RHEL 6, though.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is available in epel repository. You need to run the following command as root to install epel repos on your RedHat/CentOS machine:

```
 rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

Then

```
yum update
```

and then

```
yum install google-perftools google-perftools-devel
```

If you are running RHEL6 then you have to install the following as per the link you sent:

```
rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/epel-i386/pprof-2.0-3.el6.2.noarch.rpm.html
```

The above should do it.